# How do I reconnect with cache files

Tags: cache

I have made a scene with smoke in it. The smoke is baked and the cache-files are in a folder next to the blender-file. I work on a Mac and when bringing the project to another Mac the cache is recognised as long as I do not change the name of the Blender-file. 
When I bring the project to a Windows PC, the scene does not include the smoke. Cache folder and Blender-file is still side by side (Dropbox).
How do I reconnect to the baked cache-files on the new Windows-PC?